# IIB10 - BIP3732E: The specified WSDL binding could not be found in the supplied WSDL file

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, ibm-integration-bus

I've created a simple message set in Integration Toolkit 10.0.0.7.

Also created a message flow by drag-and-dropping a WSDL file.

But when deploying, getting this:

BIP2087E: Integration node was unable to process the internal configuration message.

The entire internal configuration message failed to be processed successfully.

Use the messages following this message to determine the reasons for the failure. If the problem cannot be resolved after reviewing these messages, contact your IBM Support center. Enabling service trace may help determine the cause of the failure.

BIP4041E: Integration server 'default' received an administration request that encountered an exception.

While attempting to process an administration request, an exception was encountered. No updates have been made to the configuration of the integration server.

Review related error messages to determine why the administration request failed.

BIP3726E: Failed to setup SOAP transport for node SOAP Input.

The SOAP nodes rely on the configuration of the SOAP transport layer within the integration node, and this has not been initialised correctly. The node will not be operational until the problems have been corrected.

Determine the cause of the error and correct it. Subsequent error messages may contain more information.

BIP3732E: The specified WSDL binding MSETSOAP_HTTP_Binding could not be found in the supplied WSDL file MSET/msetdefns/MSETDEFINITIONService.wsdl.

The WSDL binding MSETSOAP_HTTP_Binding from the target namespace MSETDEFNS associated with message set was not found in the WSDL file MSET/msetdefns/MSETDEFINITIONService.wsdl. This could be because the WSDL file is missing, invalid or corrupt.

Determine the cause of the error and correct it. Ensure that the WSDL file is valid and that it validates correctly.

I've checked: WSDL is ok. SoapUI opens it as well.

What could be the root of problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what IBM expert says:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/352486/bip3732e-the-specified-wsdl-binding-could-not-be-f.html#answer-352715

Also, my workaround:

When dragging WSDL onto message flow and choosing HTTP node instead SOAP - everything runs successfully!

Good luck!